# Node JS express not serve SOME static files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm using this [angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate](https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate) and my dev env hosted on windows 10.
After runing gulp in dev mode static files moves to build dir:

```
./build
   |_js
   |_css
   |_img
   |_fonts
   |_lang
```

Also in dev server configuration a have [this](https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate/blob/master/gulp/util/testServer.js):

```
app.use(express.static(dir)); //where dir is './build'.
```

localhost:3000/js/main.js, ../css/style.css, etc... works fine!

But why **some** static files is inaccessible ? For example:

localhost:3000/js/main.js.map - redirects to localhost:3000 or

localhost:3000/lang/en.json - redirects to localhost:3000

Comment: there is not a folder called `lang` in `build` folder structure you have given here.

Comment: It's my custom under angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate. Edited..

Comment: Are you sure those files exist?

Comment: Try `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, dir)));`

Comment: @Artur, I was trying that, but still not working.

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus, files 100% exists.

Comment: Does it depend on file extension? Like json and map files are not served, all the others are?

Comment: @TamasHegedus, yes and thank you! Your question was decisive :) In angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate exists setting assetExtensions which allow files types! Looks like authors forgot to allow .map files by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate` serves files by their extension by default. [Here is the list](https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate/blob/master/gulp/config.js#L34) of what extensions are allowed. You can extend this list after you scaffolded your application.